# For Loop: How do I see plot for different columns in Spyder "Plots" Window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Currently, I ran the below code in Spyder. And I only see the last plot (Age) in my "Plots" window. How can I see the plot for each column as the code loops through the columns?

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
 
df=pd.DataFrame ({'Sex': ['M', 'M', 'F'],
                  'Age': ['19', '88','14'] 
                  })
 
for col in df.columns:
    c=df.groupby(col)[col].count()
 
    sns.barplot(x=c.index,y=c.values)
```

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and add `plt.show()` inside the loop, after `sns.barplot(...)`. See [code and plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y2S8.png)

Comment: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with spyder. This is a standard matplotlib/seaborn requirement.